# How works exactly the bonus tile that gives you '+1 river shipping'

Tags: terra-mystica

There's a bonus tile with a +1 river shipping distance. On the official rules on appendix IV: bonus tiles, talking about the shipping half of the tile it reads (translated from Spanish) 'Moreover, your distance shipping value adds 1 during second phase. On last round, it doesn't counts on final point count'. It seemed quite clear untill we actually played it. The question is:

- Does the uses of this tile means you add +1 automatically without investing resources?
- Does this implies you must use one of your phase 2 actions in order to use it?

For the sake of gaming balance on our gaming group, we have established the house rule that you must use the first action on phase 2 using this tile, so you add the +1 for free. 
But, there's an official position about using an action or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tile simply gives you 1 more shipping value than you have from your shipping track for that round. So if you haven't upgraded your shipping at all, so you have 0 shipping, then for that round, you can dig and build in places that you can reach with 1 shipping. It does NOT advance your shipping track.

Comment: This seems way more balanced than our little home-brew solution. But the rules book isn't quite clear on that, IMHO.